# Visual Studio Team Suite

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

If taken from a developers perspective, what would my team and I gain from using Visual Studio Team System and Visual Studio Team Foundation Server?

I can see some features and the like, but what have you gained from using the two versus using VS Professional and SVN (for a weak example). If there are any good links that you know of, please feel free to post them.

Answer (score 5):

Team suite will allow you to manage the entire lifecycle management in a unified framework.
It is very easy to bind your changes and source code to a build, work-items, create release notes, etc.

Comment: +1 - On the down side it's very expensive if you're only going to use it for a few features (e.g. source control)

Comment: Agreed. That said, it is well worth it. It is not that expensive, f bought through proper channels - large companies have the money, small ones alternatives (bizspark, webspark, spla renting).

Answer (score 4):

Well, lets talk 2010... ;)

You can not compare Prof + SVN with TFS and TS - reason is you msis out a LOT. The comparisong would have to include some other technologies toget on feature parity.

IMHO good points are:

- Good source control (including stable server based storage, proxies for external subteams etc.). Not saying SVN sucks, but I dont like not having locking checkouts on times, and if you run a larger / distributed team, the proxy functionaltiy really pushes performance.
- Automatded build / Continous integration (which is where CC.NET or TeamCity would come in). Unless you dont do that, plus unit testing etc. - you simply did not mention any solution for this, and in TS it is integrated, which I take as a big plus.
- Gated checkin (check in only after build server ok's the changes - harder to break builds)
- Bug tracking / work item tracking (not the best, but again - you need another product for that). I personally think it does a mediocre job there (Axosoft OnTime looks a lot better), but - well... it is integrated ;)
- Data Dude - database change script generation and handling of database versioning. Again, this is a big problematic area otherwise - third "another piece of software needed" thing.

That is a decent start at least to show you that the comparison is a lot more complicated.

Comment: Great points!  I think it valid to point out, however that the "Data Dude" stuff comes at the HIGH END of VS 2010; at least Premium(see here --> http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products)

Comment: Agreed. That said, it is well worth it. It is not that expensive, f bought through proper channels - large companies have the money, small ones alternatives (bizspark, webspark, spla renting).